# Prove that the function $d_A:X\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto\displaystyle\inf_{a\in A} d(x,a)$ is continuous.

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

> **For a metric space $(X,d)$ and a nonempty subset $A$ of $X$ prove that the function $$d_A:X\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto\displaystyle\inf_{a\in A} d(x,a)$$ is continuous.**

Choose $c\in X$ and $\delta>0.$ To show $\exists~\epsilon>0$ such that $x\in B(c,\epsilon)\implies |d_A(x)-d_A(c)|<\delta.$

Set $\displaystyle\epsilon=\frac{\delta}{2}.$

For $x\in B(c,\epsilon)$ and $a\in A,~|d(x,a)-d(a,c)|\le d(x,c)<\epsilon$ i.e. $-\epsilon<d(x,a)-d(a,c)<\epsilon.$

Now $\forall~x\in B(c,\epsilon)$ and $\forall~a\in A,~-\epsilon+d(a,c)<d(x,a)\\\implies -\epsilon+d_A(c)< d(a,x)\\\implies d_A(c)\le d_A(x)+\epsilon\\\implies d_A(c)-d_A(x)\le\epsilon\cdots(1)$

And $\forall~x\in B(c,\epsilon)$ and $\forall~a\in A,~d_A(x)\le d(x,a)<\epsilon+d(a,c)\\\implies d_A(x)-\epsilon<d(a,c)\\\implies d_A(x)-\epsilon\le d_A(c)\\\implies-\epsilon\le d_A(c)- d_A(x)\cdots(2)$

By (1) and (2), $|d_A(x)-d_A(c)|\le\epsilon<\delta.$ Thus $d_A$ is continuous.

**Am I correct?**

Comment: I think the implication $-\epsilon+d(a,c)<d(x,a)\implies-\epsilon+d(a,c)\le d_A(x)$ does not work. But you could say $-\epsilon+d(a,c)<d(x,a)\implies-\epsilon+d_A(c)<d(x,a)\implies-\epsilon+d_A(c)<d_A(x)$

Comment: The standard method to show this would be showing the $d_A$ is 1-lipschitz

Comment: @StefanH. Right you're. That implication didn't make sense. Edited.

Comment: Then, it looks good :)

Comment: What @BertrandR said, plus the fact that every infimum of k-Lipschitz functions is k-Lipschitz.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is correct, but can be shortened and strengthened a bit:

Assume $x,c\in X$ and $d(x,c)<\epsilon:=\frac\delta2$.
For each $a\in A$ we have $d(x,a)\le d(c,a)+d(x,c)<d(c,a)+\epsilon$, thus $d_A(x)<d(c,a)+\epsilon$, and therefore $d_A(x)\le d_A(c)+\epsilon$.
Similarly, we have $d(c,a)\le d(x,a)+d(x,c)<d(x,a)+\epsilon$, and therefore $d_A(c)\le d_A(x)+\epsilon$.
If we combine these, we obtain the formula $|d_A(x)-d_A(c)|\le\epsilon<\delta$ which is valid for an arbitrary choice of $x$ and $c$ in $X$. So we conclude that $d_A$ is **uniformly continuous.**